# Prove that $A$ is not invertible.

Tags: functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators

> Let $A$ be a positive self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H.$ If $\inf\limits_{\|x\|=1} \left \langle Ax, x \right \rangle = 0$ then $A$ cannot be invertible.

How do I prove it? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for giving time.

Comment: @Arthur No. I mean $\inf\limits_{\|x\|=1} \left \langle Ax, x \right \rangle = 0.$

Comment: @Alessandro There is a slight flaw in your argument. You have to use absolute value of the inner product because in general self-adjoint can very well be non-positive. Though in my case it holds true because I am only concerned about the positive self-adjoint operator.

Comment: you're right, I forgot the absolute value. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Alessandro I have failed to conclude the result from your hint. Could you please elaborate a little bit? Thanks.

Comment: @Alessandro could you please elaborate as to why do the hypothesis along with the assumption of invertibility of $A$ imply that $\|A\|_{\text {op}}$ is infinite? Unfortunately I couldn't convert your hint to a rigorous proof. That's why I am seeking for help. But nobody even bothers to  respond. I don't know why is there so much of indifference.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. My bad, forget my "hint"

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ were invertible, then $A^{1/2}$ would also be invertible (with inverse $A^{-1/2}$). In particular, $A^{1/2}$ would be bounded below - there would exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$$
\|A^{1/2}x\| \geq \epsilon\|x\|.
$$
Squaring both sides and writing out the inner product gives $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ on the left-hand-side. This should give you the contradiction you seek.

Comment: How can it be shown that if $A$ is invertible then so is $A^{\frac {1} {2}}\ $? If $A$ is an invertible positive operator does it always imply that $A^{-1}$ is also a positive operator? I am sorry to say that I am not familiar with any such result. Could you please help me in this regard? Thanks.

Comment: Also I think here you are assuming that the underlying Hilbert space is complex. What I am aware of is that every positive operator on a complex Hilbert space is self-adjoint. So here when you said that squaring both sides I get the desired contradiction what I seek, there I presume you are implicitly assuming that $A^{\frac {1} {2}}$ is self-adjoint. Though I may be wrong as I am a beginner of this topic. Feel free to give me any kind of suggestion in this regard. I need to learn and master this topic anyway.

Comment: I have understood the invertibility of $A^{\frac {1} {2}}$ when $A$ is invertible. It follows from the observations that $\text {ker} \left  (A^{\frac {1} {2}} \right ) \subseteq \text {ker} (A)$ and $\text {Im} (A) \subseteq \text {Im} \left (A^{\frac {1} {2}} \right ).$ But still I can't able to understand why $A^{\frac {1} {2}}$ is self-adjoint unless we assume the underlying Hilbert space to be complex. Eagerly waiting for your response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fanatics If $A$ is invertible, then $(\sqrt{A})^{-1} = A^{-1}\sqrt{A}$. A positive function of any positive operator is positive. We can prove both this and the previous facts using the spectral mapping theorem. In particular, if zero is not in the spectrum of $A$, it does not belong to the spectrum of $\sqrt{A}$. To make everything clear, any positive function of a selfadjoint operator is a selfadjoint operator. This is because a continuous functional calculus is a *-homomorphism, and the spectrum of any selfadjoint operator is real.

Comment: @Timur Bakiev thanks for your valuable suggestion. For your kind information let me tell you that I haven't gone through functional calculus yet. Yesterday I first came to know spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators when our instructor introduced it to us. It will take some time to digest it. But I am aware of spectral measure and integral with respect to spectral measure. The spectral theorem says that given a self-adjoint operator $A$ on Hilbert space there exists a unique spectral measure $E_A$ on the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\sigma (A)$ such that $$A = \int t\ dE_A.$$

Comment: @Fanatics well, if you know the spectral theorem, you can define a function of a selfadjoint operator using this theorem, and then prove my statements. Good luck anyway :)

Comment: @Timur Bakiev : I will try to do that and let you know if any help is required. Nice to meet you. Thanks! :)